# I'm suddenly getting 1-2 FPS instead of 60+ in games. I haven't changed anything (on purpose). Where can I start to diagnose?

Tags: graphics, display-resolution, amd-graphics, xrandr

I've got a really odd issue:

Today while using my Machine (Ubuntu 20.04 on Intel i5 + AMD R9390X) I noticed that I could no longer do audio-over-displayport. I tried `pulseaudio -k` and re-plugging the cable to no avail, so I rebooted.

Then after a reboot the resolution was locked at 1024x768. No other options in settings and any attempt to do `xrandr --newmode` failed with an error about gamma levels: `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default`

I did some googling and found I could edit /etc/default/grub and set `GRUB_GFXMODE=3440x1440`. Now I have my native resolution back, but it's also the only resolution option in settings, which makes me think that's a bit of a hacky fix. I also still don't have audio-over-displayport.

Finally, games now just don't run. Minecraft gets 1-10FPS instead of 60+, and 'golf with your friends' gets < 1 instead of 100+

I have a dedicated GPU and that's what's connected to my monitor. I haven't changed anything on purpose lately to do with GPUs etc. I installed `libolm-dev` as part of `element-desktop`, but that's the only change since last reboot.

If anyone could suggest next steps in diagnosing the problem I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,
Bill

### Update

The output of `sudo lshw -c video` looks wrong too:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Hawaii XT / Grenada XT [Radeon R9 290X/390X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 80
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff memory:c0000-dfff
```

Why `unclaimed`?